# tableView:indexPathForCell on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

Is there an equivalent method for

```
tableView:indexPathForCell
```

on Mac?

I'm trying to get the row from which a button is pressed.

Comment: What button?  Is this a view based table with a button in the view?

Comment: Yeah, it's a view based table and I have a button inside the RowView. Basically, my problem is that if the button is pressed and the row isn't "selected" the button will correspond to the selected row or row -1 (no selection) instead.

Comment: you can try "selectedRow" method in NSTableView. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstableview_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this method connected to your button.  The code needs to be in the class that's the delegate of the table view.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSInteger buttonRow = [self.tv rowForView:sender]; //tv is IBOutlet for the tableView
    NSLog(@"%ld",buttonRow);
}
```